# Can not describe an index domaine

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create a domain index called cat_index on an attribute of a table, so when I try to do:

```
select index_name from user_indexes ;
```

I get as result:

```
cat_index 
DR$cat_index$K
DR$cat_index$I
DR$cat_index$X
cat_index
```

The problem is when I try to describe DR$cat_index$K it shows an error:

> object DR$cat_index$K doesnt exist

While when I try to `describe DR$cat_index$I` I can see the result with no error.

Can anyone of you explain to me that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi how can cat_index appear twice?

Anyway, describe will not describe an index.  It must have found a table with the same name.  Try user_tables to see if this is the case.

What do you want to know about the indexes?  You can select * from user_indexes instead of describe.